# wkhtmltopdf (knp snappy bundle) Wrong text selection and wrong wrapping

Tags: symfony, wkhtmltopdf

I am use "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master" for symfony 2.7

I generate pdf by using

```
$this->knp_snappy_pdf->generateFromHtml( $html,  $file_path, $options);
```

Then i open pdf in chrome and try selection text i see 
this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/soKJh.jpg

But if i use http://pdfcrowd.com/ and the same html i see 
normal text selection

My $options

```
array(
            'images' => true,
            'no-pdf-compression' => true,
            'page-width' => '150mm',
            'page-height' => '180mm',
            'minimum-font-size' => '2',
            'dpi' => 300,
            'disable-smart-shrinking' => true,
            'zoom' => '0.6',
        )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Adding screenshots of the normal situation and of what your tool should normally produce would probably help seeing the difference. You can also embed images in your question so that it is even clearer.

Comment: That is normal selection( I get this pdf from online generator) https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3978952/10868709/cedbe3e4-80a7-11e5-89c1-5faa8df4966a.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I can't find answer, so I use mpdf. It is better and works right out of the box immediately